# Is it possible to launch ec2 instance from a template using .net sdk

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

Is it possible to launch ec2 instance from a launch template using .net sdk. I know I can create one with the same spec using the ec2 class but I have a launch template on the web console that I use today manually. I want to give my end users the ability to spin up machines from an app and use these templates to create the machines.

Comment: You can use [CloudFormation](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/) to create resources. Check the [AWS CloudFormation Programming with the AWS SDK for .NET](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v2/developer-guide/cloudformation-apis-intro.html) for details.

Comment: ok will do thanks for the direction